# "Decode" (?) CSS (Contains %20 and others)

Tags: css

I was given html files but the css looks like this:

```
<link href="data:text/css;charset=utf-8,body%2Etheme%2Ddark%20%7B%0Abackground%2Dcolor%3A%20%23333%20%21important%3B%0A%7D%0A%2Elink%20%7B%0Afill%3A%20none%3B%0A%7D%0A%2Etheme%2Ddark%20%2Elink%20%7B%0A%7D%0A%2Ed3heatmap%20%7B%0Aposition%3A%20relative%3B%0Awidth%3A%20820px%3B%0Aheight%3A%20700px%3B%0Aoverflow%3A%20hidden%3B%0A%7D%0A%2Ed3heatmap%20%2Edomain%20%7B%0Afill%3A%20none%3B%0Astroke%3A%20none%3B%0A%7D%0A%2Ed3heatmap%20%2Eaxis%20%7B%0Aoverflow%3A%20hidden%3B%0A%7D%0A%2Ed3heatmap%20%2Eaxis%20line%20%7B%0Afill%3A%20none%3B%0Astroke%3A%20%23AAA%3B%0Astroke%2Dwidth%3A%201px%3B%0Ashape%2Drendering%3A%20crispEdges%3B%0A%7D%0A%2Ed3heatmap%20%2Eaxis%20text%2C%20%2Ed3heatmap%2Dtip%20%7B%0Afont%2Dsize%3A%2015px%3B%0Afont%2Dfamily%3A%20Ubuntu%20Sans%2C%20Segoe%20UI%2C%20Lucida%20Grande%2C%20sans%2Dserif%3B%0A%7D%0A%2Ed3heatmap%20%2Eaxis%20rect%20%7B%0Acursor%3A%20pointer%3B%0A%7D%0A%2Einner%20%7B%0Aposition%3A%20relative%3B%0A%7D%0A%2Einfo%20%7B%0Aposition%3A%20absolute%3B%0Aleft%3A%2020px%3B%0Atop%3A%2090px%3B%0Awidth%3A%20160px%3B%0Aheight%3A%20140px%3B%0Atext%2Dalign%3A%20right%3B%0Afont%2Dsize%3A%2040px%3B%0Apadding%2Dtop%3A%20118px%3B%0A%7D%0A%2Ed3heatmap%20text%20%7B%0Acursor%3A%20default%3B%0A%7D%0A%2Ed3heatmap%20%2Ebrush%20%2Eextent%7B%0Afill%2Dopacity%3A%200%2E15%3B%0Astroke%2Dwidth%3A%201px%3B%0A%7D%0A%2EcolDend%20%7B%0Aposition%3A%20absolute%3B%0Aoverflow%3A%20hidden%3B%0A%7D%0A%2ErowDend%20%7B%0Aposition%3A%20absolute%3B%0Aoverflow%3A%20hidden%3B%0A%7D%0A%2Ecolormap%20%7B%0Aposition%3A%20absolute%3B%0Aoverflow%3A%20hidden%3B%0A%7D%0A%2Etheme%2Ddark%20text%20%7B%0Afill%3A%20%23E2E2E2%3B%0A%7D%0A%2Ehighlighting%20%2Ecolormap%20%2Edatapt%20%7B%0Aopacity%3A%200%2E2%3B%0A%7D%0A%2Ehighlighting%20%2Ecolormap%20%2Edatapt%2Ehighlight%20%7B%0Aopacity%3A%201%3B%0A%7D%0A%2Ehighlighting%20%2Eaxis%20g%2Etick%2Efaded%20%7B%0Aopacity%3A%200%2E4%20%21important%3B%0A%7D%0A%2Ed3heatmap%2Dtip%20%7B%0Afont%2Dsize%3A%2013px%3B%0Acolor%3A%20white%3B%0Abackground%2Dcolor%3A%20%23444%3B%0Apadding%3A%206px%2012px%3B%0Abox%2Dshadow%3A%203px%203px%205px%200px%20rgba%280%2C%200%2C%200%2C%200%2E22%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%2Etheme%2Ddark%20%2Ed3heatmap%2Dtip%20%7B%0Abackground%2Dcolor%3A%20white%3B%0Acolor%3A%20%23444%3B%0A%7D%0A%2Ed3heatmap%2Dtip%20table%20%7B%0Aborder%2Dcollapse%3A%20separate%3B%0Aborder%2Dspacing%3A%202px%3B%0A%7D%0A%2Ed3heatmap%2Dtip%20th%2C%20%2Ed3heatmap%2Dtip%20td%20%7B%0Apadding%3A%200%201px%3B%0A%7D%0A" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Is there some script out there to convert it to more standard formatting?  I'm not even sure how to search for what kind of formatting this is.

Comment: It's a link, so why try to decode it?

Comment: Because I need to change the colors and whatnot.

Comment: its URL Encoded, copy/paste to https://www.urldecoder.org (or decodeURIComponent("xxx"); in JS)

Comment: Alex K., thank you for actually providing an answer to the question.

Comment: @AlexK. you should post that as an answer.